# Reasons a text input will not autocomplete in a modal in AngularJS & Bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a text input that is in an AngualrJS modal. If I take the input out of the modal autocomplete works correctly. While the input is in the modal the autocomplete suggestions from the browser do not work. If I enter values while the input is out of the modal and place it back in. The browser will then autocomplete suggestions while it was out of the modal.

What could prevent the input from autocompleting from the browser correctly while the input is inside the modal?

The input is set up to accept either a name or an email address. I've been using the autocomplete setting `autocomplete="username"` so that it will autofill either a name or an email address.

A quick example of the input.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="nameInput.html">
<name-input-modal>

  <form name="nameinput" novalidate ng-class="{submitted: formSubmitted}"
        ng-submit="formSubmitted=true;">
    <label for="userInput">Name</label>
    <input required name="user" id="userInput" type="text"
           autocomplete="username"
           class="form-control ng-valid ng-valid-required">   
  </form>

</name-input-modal>
</script>
```

Comment: The solution to the issue, that there were multiple forms in a modal. The solution was to remove the individual forms and wrap the modal in one form.